# why my project do not need typescript definition files?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I can import and use **.js** libraries in my **.ts** project without any problem

> I do not use *.d.ts files anywhere

and I want to know how this is possible?

Comment: Why would you think it wasn't possible?..    You don't get as good a code completion type checking, but it's pretty normal to include JS in TS..

Comment: You can turn of it. Change allowJs in tsconfig to false. [ts docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowJs)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible because the typeScript language is being translated to javaScript

Think of it as an extension of class

Obviate accuracy

TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to plain JavaScript

Comment: so what is the use case of *.d.ts files?!

Comment: Do you ask what the benefits in type Script?
https://medium.com/swlh/the-major-benefits-of-using-typescript-aa8553f5e2ed

Comment: @AminDavids.   JavaScript has no type information, so that's the point of *.d.ts files.  Do you understand what is meant by type information?  If not you possibly don't even need to be using Typescript.

Comment: no , I just think using d.ts files when we want import some .js code in our .ts code is a Necessity. is that true , or Im wrong .